# What does 'right' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a part of [Les Miserables anime review](http://www.themanime.org/viewreview.php?id=1010):

> ... If you really have the time to watch an anime, do yourself a favor and read the book. This is a mere shadow of what Les Miserables really is. Still a fantastic series in its own **right**--but as a rabid fan of the novel and the musical, I feel I am being generous with a fourth star...

I don't really understand what he meant with 'right' in this context.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/own+right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[in one's own right](https://www.google.com/search?q=in%20one%27s%20own%20right%20meaning)** is an idiom, meaning

> as a result of one's own claims, qualifications, or efforts, rather than an association with someone else.
>   *"he was already established as a poet in his own right"*

A good approximation (though not exact) of its meaning is "by itself" or "on its own", e.g. *"Still a fantastic series in its own right, but ..."* roughly means *"A fantastic series (by itself) anyway, but ..."*